# i can't retrieve an image from the image url link in django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

**I use the CharField for the image url in the django model bt can't retrieve image in the detail page of food , this app is food app and i use default parameter as a food a placeholder image :

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here


    class Item(models.Model):
        def __str__(self):
            return self.item_name
    
        item_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        item_desc = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        item_price = models.IntegerField()
        item_image = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="https://p.kindpng.com/picc/s/79-798754_hoteles-y-centros-vacacionales-dish-placeholder-hd-png.png")
```

Comment: how you are retrieving on detail page ?

Comment: {% extends 'food/base.html' %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <img src="{{ item.item_image }}" class="card" height="300px">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <h1>{{ item.item_name }}</h1>
   <h2>{{ item.item_desc }}</h2>
   <h3>${{ item.item_price }}</h3>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

Comment: can you check in db what is the value for item_image. also check in view page source that <img src= is getting any value

Comment: @SaribegFarmanian Edit [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66317605/#comment117247966_66317605) right into your question to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ImageField instead of CharField in models.py and use upload_to for attribute
also you have to set MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL in setting.py and then adding the static url in the urls.py
see this example:

models.py:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures/',default='pictures/None/none.jpg')
```

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'pictures'
MEDIA_URL = '/pictures/'
```

also you should create the pictures path in your main file

in your urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here 
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and don't forget to install pillow

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code on how to fetch an image from the views to template.

`<img src="{{ item.item_image.url }}" class="card" height="300px">`

it would be helpful for others to check the error if you could provide the codes from views.py and html file that is connected to that problem.

Comment: thanks for answer ,i solved the problem , thanks for your kindness :)